# EOF character is not detected when typing line of text first?

Tags: c, input, eof, getc

```
char ch;
while((ch=getc(stdin))!=EOF)
{
    putc(ch,stdout);
}
```

As we know that EOF character can be inputted by `ctrl-z`.

I ran the program two times:-

1- When I input `ctrl-z`, the loop gets terminated, which is acceptable.

2- When I input `ctrl-z` along with some other text like `demo` and then press `ctrl-z`, then the loop does not get terminated.

So my question is that why the loop is getting terminated only by inputing `ctrl-z` alone?

Comment: Which terminal/shell is being used?

Comment: @user2864740: what it means?

Comment: i.e. xterm/bash? windows/cmd.exe?

Comment: I have used the  second one

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` is **not** a character that you can put into a stream. It's a meta-control character that can be returned by `getc`, but can not be written. `ctrl-z` does not technically send `EOF`, it sends `SIGTSTP` to the process and `getc` is programmed to respond to it by returning `EOF`.

Comment: I agree to it, but why this is not happening in second case

Comment: Are you actually typing `demo` and then pressing `ctrl-z` or typing `^z`? The latter will not work on most terminals.

Comment: I am typing `demo` and then pressing `ctrl-z`